# how can I add the apexchart in a pdf using react pdf library the page is mapped and the data of the graph is mapped as per page

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-pdf, react-apexcharts

I am creating a portfolio website where a persons every investment will be visible and on that i have added a function that downloads pdf report getting details from and mapping every investment on single page base and i have to also add a graph as per the specific investment on every page how should i do that

I try using chart id method and then convert it to image but it is not getting mapped

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).